# How to retrieve hidden field value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, master-pages, hidden-field, contentplaceholder

I've asp.net web site , I used master page for the design. I've child page which is placed in the **contentplaceholder**. On the child page i used one hidden field as -

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="This is hidden text"/>
```

I want to display the hidden field value using alert() function from javascript on the **page load event**. How to do this?

I tried following thing in my script but it is not working-

```
(function msgShow() {

        var e1 = document.getElementById('Hidden');
        alert(e1.value);
    })();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? You get an error, null value, undefined...

Comment: @Viruzzo: I don't get any error. I just display my page without the alert message.

Comment: If you put an `alert('Hello World!');` before the getElementById, does it show?

Comment: Your hidden element should be there when you call your msgShow function e.g call your function after DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: @Virusso:yes alert('hello world') is working

Comment: @bsrykt:thanks, i tried following thing and it is working `window.onload = function msgShow() { alert(document.getElementById('Hidden1').value); }`.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#Hidden1').val());
});
```

without jQuery you do:

```
alert(document.getElementById('Hidden1').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.alert(document.getElementById("Hidden1").value);
```

Make sure this code is executed after the DOM is ready.

Comment: How to ensure that the code will be executed after DOM is ready?

Comment: You can do this using jQuery's [ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) method.  If not using jQuery just place your JavaScript code at the end of the body, this has [performance benefits](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) too as the loading of the JS won't block page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with any other element, you can get it with `document.getElementById('Hidden1').value`

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code given below to know how to get

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function printIt(){
   alert(document.getElementById('abcId').value);
   alert(document.formName.elements['abcName'].value);
}
</script>

<h1>Access Hidden value in JavaScript</h1>
<form name="formName">
    <input type="hidden" id="abcId" name="abcName" 
                  value="I am Hidden value"/>

    <input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="printIt()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('Hidden1').value;
```

and alert the return value

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript:

```
var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript">
        function dis() {
            var j = document.getElementById("<%= Hidden1.ClientID %>").value;
            alert(j);
        }
    </script>`

`<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" value="Hello" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return dis();" />`

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure not to reference a DOM element before it exists - like I just did and spent an hour trying to figure why even HelloWorld would not work.